# Why aren't variables interpolated in `constant` declarations?

Tags: constants, raku, string-interpolation

```
use v6.d;

my Str $foo = 'Hello';
my constant $BAR = "--$foo--";
say $BAR;
```

## OUTPUT:

```
Use of uninitialized value element of type Str in string context.
Methods .^name, .raku, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to something meaningful.
  in block  at deleteme.raku line 4
----
```

## Expected OUTPUT:

```
--Hello--
```

The same thing happens without the `my` or with `our` in place of `my`.

```
[187] > $*DISTRO
macos (12.6)
[188] > $*KERNEL
darwin
[189] > $*RAKU
Raku (6.d)
```

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value assigned to a `constant` is evaluated at compile time, not runtime. This means that constant values can be calculated as part of the compilation and cached.

Regular assignments happen at runtime. Thus, in:

```
my Str $foo = 'Hello';
my constant $BAR = "--$foo--";
```

The assignment to `$foo` has not taken place at the time `"--$foo--"` is evaluated. By contrast, if `$foo` were to be a constant, the value is available at compile time and interpolated, so:

```
my constant $foo = 'Hello';
my constant $BAR = "--$foo--";
say $BAR;
```

Produces:

```
--Hello--
```

Comment: You should probably mention the alternative of `BEGIN my $foo = 'Hello';` instead of `my constant $foo = 'Hello';` so Jim can then write `$foo = 'something else';` in later code and not get a `Cannot assign to an immutable value` error.

Comment: While it's possible to do, I don't think I'd write it that way; it seems to invite confusion. I'd write it more like `my constant $hello = 'Hello'; my $foo = $hello;` or similar (that is, differentiate the constant initial value and the mutable variable).

Comment: Yeah, that's the way. Thanks. I'll leave my original comment so there's adequate context for yours.